# Conditional Merging of Rows to One Row with Sum and Average

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this:

| Student ID | Class | Week | Units | Grade | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 2 | 50 | 90 |
| 1 | A | 1 | 3 | 100 | 120 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 3 | 70 | 30 |
| 2 | B | 4 | 1 | 80 | 60 |
| 2 | B | 4 | 1 | 90 | 60 |
| 2 | B | 5 | 2 | 100 | 90 |

What I would like to do is to create a new data.frame as such. For every rows that have identical ID, Class and Week, merge all of them into one row so that I have weighted average of Grades based on Units, and a simple sum of Duration and Units.

So in this case I wish to get a table that looks like this:

| Student ID | Class | Week | Units | Grade | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 5 | 80 | 210 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 3 | 70 | 30 |
| 2 | B | 4 | 2 | 85 | 120 |
| 2 | B | 5 | 2 | 100 | 90 |

How could I achieve this task?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Student_ID, Class, Week) %>%
  summarise(Grade = weighted.mean(Grade, Units), 
            Duration = sum(Duration),
            Units = sum(Units)) %>%
  relocate(Units, .after = Week)


# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   Student_ID, Class [3]
  Student_ID Class  Week Units Grade Duration
       <int> <chr> <int> <int> <dbl>    <int>
1          1 A         1     5    80      210
2          1 B         1     3    70       30
3          2 B         4     2    85      120
4          2 B         5     2   100       90
```